# Built-in PHP function to reset the indexes of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Example:

```
$arr = array(1 => 'Foo', 5 => 'Bar', 6 => 'Foobar');
/*... do some function so $arr now equals:
    array(0 => 'Foo', 1 => 'Bar', 2 => 'Foobar');
*/
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `array_values($arr)`.  That will return a regular array of all the values (indexed numerically).

[PHP docs for array_values](http://php.net/array_values)

Comment: You're welcome.  Thank goodness for php and millions of array functions.

Comment: Brian, curse PHP and millions of array functions. ;)

Answer (score 4):

```
array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, `array_values()` will not preserve string keys. If your array has a mix of string keys and numeric keys (which is probably an indication of bad design, but may happen nonetheless), you can use a function like:

```
function reset_numeric_keys($array = array(), $recurse = false) {
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($recurse && is_array($value)) {
            $value = reset_numeric_keys($value, true);
        }
        if(gettype($key) == 'integer') {
            $returnArray[] = $value;
        } else {
            $returnArray[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $returnArray;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Not that I know of, you might have already checked functions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_array.asp)

but I can imagine writing a simple function myself

```
resetarray($oldarray)
{
for(int $i=0;$i<$oldarray.count;$i++)
     $newarray.push(i,$oldarray[i])

return $newarray;
}
```

I am little edgy on syntax but I guess u got the idea.

Comment: -1: Not only is the syntax wrong, but the logic is too. Not to mention that correct answers had been posted.